Apache configuration question ( Google Managed certificate and HTTPS LB )
If I follow this instruction, I am able to get the hello world! on browser.
After getting a domain name, and using cloud dns to point the VM external ip to that domain name, I am also able to get the hello world! after inputting the domain name on browser, eg newdany.us.to
Now i want to use SSL, https://newdany.us.to so that browser returns me the hello world! with https. I was able to create my https lb, using google managed certificate. The certificate was properly provision. I also made the change on Cloud DNS to point to new LB IP, however I get this error when i type https://newdany.us.to
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. retried and the latest reset reason: remote connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111

I am hoping the community can point me in the right direction with the changes that needs to be made inside the server so that https works. Thanking you in advance.
My 000-default.conf file is below
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName newdany.us.to
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

I have added this line ServerName newdany.us.to in the 000-default.conf file however I am not sure if that is correct.

Created my frontend


I created a new index file at /var/www/sites/abc/index.html
created a new conf file called abc.com.conf
change DocumentRoot to make it point to new index file
disabled the old config with: sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
activated new one: sudo a2ensite abc.com.conf
sudo service apache2 reload


Did you create a new frontend for the load balancer to handle HTTPS (Port 443) connections?

It is OK to add the hostname to 000-default.conf, but typically you would disable that configuration and create a new virtual host configuration for each domain you want Apache to support. There are good tutorials on the Internet that explains what Virtual Hosts are and how to configure them for Apache.

Works now thanks John

Does Mr. John's comment resolved this concern?

It is hard to say but redoing everything did fix the issue, so its hard to say exactly what fixed issue.
